# Kotlin Flows Java Interop Callback

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I´ve been looking for a suitable solution or best practice when I want to use Kotlin Flows with ordinary callbacks. My use case is that I write a kotlin library that uses Kotlin Flow internally and i have to assume that the users will use Java for instance. So I thought that the best solution is to overload a basic callback interface to my flow method and call it in `collect` something like this:

```
class KotlinClass {

    interface Callback {
        fun onResult(result: Int)
    }

    private fun foo() = flow {
        for (i in 1..3) {
            emit(i)
        }
    }

    fun bar(callback: Callback) {
        runBlocking {
            foo().collect { callback.onResult(it) }
        }
    }

  private fun main() {
    bar(object : Callback {
        override fun onResult(result: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
}
```

and in my Java Application i can simply use it like that:

```
public class JavaClass {

    public void main() {
        KotlinClass libraryClass = new KotlinClass();
        libraryClass.bar(new KotlinClass.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(int result) {
                // TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

I am not sure whats the way to go because I would like to have my Kotlin library that uses Flows usable in a good fashion for Java and Kotlin.

I came across `callbackFlow` but that seems to be only if I want to let´s call it flow-ify a callback-based API? Because I am quite new to Kotlin and Flows please apologise if my question is flawed in cause of missing some basic concepts of kotlin.

Answer (score 6):

I would give the Java client more control over the flow. I would add a `onStart` and `onCompletion` method to your callback interface. Beside this I would use an own `CoroutineScope` - maybe customizable from the Java client. And I would not block the calling thread from within the Kotlin function - no `runBlocking`.

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class KotlinClass {
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    interface FlowCallback {
        @JvmDefault
        fun onStart() = Unit

        @JvmDefault
        fun onCompletion(thr: Throwable?) = Unit
        fun onResult(result: Int)
    }

    private fun foo() = flow {
        for (i in 1..3) {
            emit(i)
        }
    }

    fun bar(flowCallback: FlowCallback) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            foo().onStart { flowCallback.onStart() }
                .onCompletion { flowCallback.onCompletion(it) }
                .collect { flowCallback.onResult(it) }
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }    
}
```

Now the Java client is in full control how to start, collect and cancel the flow. For example you could use a latch to wait for completion, set an timeout and cancel the couroutine scope. This looks in the first place like a lot of code, but typically you will need this kind of flexibility.

```
public class JavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        KotlinClass libraryClass = new KotlinClass();
        libraryClass.bar(new KotlinClass.FlowCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(@Nullable Throwable thr) {
                latch.countDown();
            }


            @Override
            public void onResult(int result) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        });

        try {
            latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } finally {
            libraryClass.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what i don´t completely understand is the part with the `countdownLatch`, do I really need to close the coroutineScope from my Java Library or can I just terminate it when it is done within my Kotlin Library?

Comment: You could close the `coroutineScope` from Kotlin as well, the same is true for blocking the calling thread. But your question was, what would be a good API. And if you do this in your library, you are very opinionated, how the client use you. From my point of view is it better to let the client decide if blocking the thread is a good idea and how long will be a timeout.

Comment: Thing is that I really want to hide all the threading in the kotlin lib and the java lib should only get a callback on the main thread for each collected result of the flow

Comment: Thanks for giving these ideas for Java interop of Kotlin Flow :heart:

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a interface in the Kotlin code. You can define bar like that:

```
 fun bar(callback: (Int) -> Unit) {
     runBlocking {
         foo().collect { callback(it) }
     }
 }
```

From the Java code you can call the function like that:

```
public class JavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KotlinClass libraryClass = new KotlinClass();
        libraryClass.bar(v -> { System.out.println(v); return Unit.INSTANCE; });
    } 
}
```

Comment: That´s a valid suggestion but I thought to use `return Unit.INSTANCE` in my java code would be bad practice like described here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop ? To use that `Unit` class in my java code do  I need to add some kotlin dependencies or so because I am not able to use this out of the box?

Comment: This text says "At present there is no way to define a parameter type for use as a lambda from both Java and Kotlin such that it feels idiomatic from both languages. The current recommendation is to prefer the function type despite the degraded experience from Java when the return type is Unit.". If you are using kotlin in a Java project, it should already include Kotlin stdlib as dependency, shouldn't it? If your lib will be used exclusively from Java, you can also try the last suggestion  "Defining a named, SAM interface in Java".

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wondering for a general solution. Here's our version of enhancement from [@rene answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608248/3763032).

1. Accept a generic type
2. A configurable `coroutineScope`

```kotlin
// JavaFlow.kt
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onCompletion
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onStart
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@InternalCoroutinesApi
class JavaFlow<T>(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
) {

    interface OperatorCallback <T> {
        @JvmDefault
        fun onStart() = Unit

        @JvmDefault
        fun onCompletion(thr: Throwable?) = Unit
        fun onResult(result: T)
    }

    fun collect(
        flow: Flow<T>,
        operatorCallback: OperatorCallback<T>,
    ) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            flow
                .onStart { operatorCallback.onStart() }
                .onCompletion { operatorCallback.onCompletion(it) }
                .collect { operatorCallback.onResult(it) }
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Java caller-side:

```java
// code omitted...
new JavaFlow<File>().collect(
        // compressImageAsFlow is our actual kotlin flow extension
        FileUtils.compressImageAsFlow(file, activity),
        new JavaFlow.OperatorCallback<File>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(File result) {
                // do something with the result here
                SafeSingleton.setFile(result);
            }
        }
);


// or using lambda with method references
// new JavaFlow<File>().collect(
//        FileUtils.compressImageAsFlow(file, activity),
//        SafeSingleton::setFile
// );

// Change coroutineScope to Main
// new JavaFlow<File>(CoroutineScopeKt.MainScope()).collect(
//        FileUtils.compressImageAsFlow(file, activity),
//        SafeSingleton::setFile
// );
```

> `OperatorCallback.onStart` and `OperatorCallback.onCompletion` is optional, override it as needed.